# Squid Reverse Proxy alternating between destinations

Tags: pfsense

I'm faced with with an odd issues I can not explain. After having setup the Squid Reverse Proxy in pfSense, 1 of the 2 mappings I've setup keeps alternating between destinations, while the other mapping consistently goes to the correct destination.

[image]

Both mappings are identical (as far as I can tell)
[image]
[image]

I cannot explain why [http://skami.steuff.net](http://skami.steuff.net/) keeps alternating between the two different webservers. There is no load balancing involved.

As for the bonus confusion whenever I do a cache refresh the page it seems to stay on the same webserver.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://test.steuff.net/

http://skami.steuff.net/

Comment: Does that site have load balancing on the web server?

Comment: @RonMaupin It does not, I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be several bugs when using squid with pfsense 2.2. I believe the answer is somewhere around the topic in this thread. I have the same problem after ugrading pfsense to 2.2 from 2.1.1. https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=87280.15

I have 7 servers behind my pfsense and it's working with three of them activated, but when i activate the 4th, i get the same error as you.

Unfortunately i have not been able to work this out so i'll be happy for a solution. (I am thinking about downgrading my pfsense to 2.1.1)

Comment: I will try to downgrade and let you know the results.

Comment: Going back to 2.1.5 seems to have solved the issue. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (squid3 reverseproxy alternates backend-servers) and would like to know if it's been fixed with 2.2.5?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few years but I'll share my experience for future reference: I had the same problem and solved it by removing spaces on my web servers. I can see you have a web server called "Win7 Test", change that to "Win7_test" and that should do the trick (at least it did it for me).